# ffmpeg audio and video out of sync when using the raw format

Tags: video, ffmpeg, yuv

I have 2 .webm files, one contains video, the other one audio. I need to produce a single mp4 file containing both video and audio, in sync. Here is what i try to do:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.33 -i user_17624_1-1762.webm -i user_17624_2-1767.webm -r 15 output_good.mp4
```

-ss by 0.33s is because video started 0.33s before audio - 1762 and 1767 are frame numbers, so they are 5 frames off, and 15 fps.

Doing this, i get a perfect recording where video and audio are in sync over the entire file.

But the thing is, i need to do some alterations of the video frames, and i do it my a C app manipulating the bytes in a raw video stream, so i can't do it this way, i need to transcode to RAW first, then manipulate, then encode mp4 back from the raw. Removing my C app from the chain to make sure it's not the problem, it boils down to:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:00.33 -i user_17624_1-1762.webm -an -r 15 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 ./video.pipe &
ffmpeg -i user_17624_2-1767.webm -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le ./audio.pipe &
ffmpeg -an -r 15 -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p -s 1920x1080 -i ./video.pipe -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -i ./audio.pipe -r 15 output_bad.mp4
```

resulting in yes, recording where audio and video are way off from each other, and seems to be also fluctuate over the file duration.

What am i doing wrong with these video transcodings? Help me please :)

Mikhail

Comment: Of course, first thing i tried is to convert these ,webm files into mp4s and then use them for conversion into the raw... that didn't help. Even with -g 1.

Answer (score 0):

Answer proved to be simple, -async 10000

Comment: async has been deprecated,  use aresample filter instead

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue when I changed the video pixel format to yuv420, but it got solved when I increased the framerate

You can try by increasing fps : 
-framerate 120